# Upgrading from postgresql 9 to 11

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-11

I'm using a Linux server, I want to upgrade postgresql from the version 9 to 11. I have created a dump of my database. Then I have installed postgresql 11, now I want to import the dump to postgresql 11, I run the command

`pg_restore -h localhost -d dbLitstUsers -U postgres .dataBasebackup` but get the error

```
pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.14) in file header
```

How can I fix this error ?

Comment: you need to take the backup with `pg_dump` from version 11. But why not go straight to 14?

Comment: this is the choice of the client to upgrade to the version 11

Comment: pg_dump is used to extract a PostgreSQL database not to import a database

Comment: Yes, but you need to do it with the one from the target version

Comment: I can only warn against upgrading to v11. Use a more recent version.

Answer (score 0):

You must have used a pg_dump from v12 or higher.  That generates a custom dump in a format (1.14) which is not compatible with older pg_restore.  Retake the dump with the pg_dump coming with the version you want to restore to.

Comment: Or use the same version of `pg_restore` to do the restore.